# How to enable javascript debugger in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-9

I've only got options to inspect html and css, the script tab shown in the docs is missing.

[image: The Debugger]

[image: Advanced options]

Comment: That's probably an administrator setting.  If your network administrator has hidden the tab, you'll have to talk to him.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the comment, confirmed the admins have not set any policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with Window's updater, IT ended up re-imaging the entire computer.  Unfortunately the specific answer here will remain a mystery.